# css 3d rotate example different size in safari than chrome

Tags: css, rotatetransform

I found an example of a 3d cube rotation hover effect that works great except for one thing.  When I view it in chrome it's normal sized, and when I view it in safari it's double sized.

I really have no idea why this is happening since I don't see any zoom or webkit-scale happening, any thoughts on this?

http://jsfiddle.net/QMQLQ/

HTML:

```
<div class='box-scene'>
    <div class='box'>
        <div class='front face'>
            <img src='http://placehold.it/180x180/' alt=''>
        </div>
        <div class="side face">
            <p>This is back</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='box-scene'>
    <div class='box'>
        <div class='front face'>
            <img src='http://placehold.it/180x180/' alt=''>
        </div>
        <div class="side face">
            <p>This is back</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box-scene {
    -webkit-perspective: 700;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;

    z-index: 999;
}
.box-scene:hover .box {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-90deg);
}
.box {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1,1);
    width: 180px;
    height: 180px;
    position: relative;

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 90px 90px -90px;

    /* float: left; */
    margin: 30px auto;


}

.face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible; 

    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.front {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    z-index: 2;
    background: #d9d9d9;
}
.side {
    background: #9dcc78;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    z-index: 1;
    left: 180px;
}
```

Comment: look the same on windows 7, chrome 36 / safari 5.0.5

Comment: i tested it and in safari and chrome it have same view.